# Fully Uninstall opendjk-11 from WSL

Tags: java, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, java-11

I am Python programmer but wanted to use Java/Scala for a project (so learning Java/Scala).

In my Windows Subsystem Linux (WSL) I had previously installed OpenJDK v 11. I wanted to replace the OpenJdk 11.0.07 with a lower version or Java 8 because one of the programs I run needs Java 8.

When I look into Window's control panel, I do not see java (I meant I removed manually from Control Panel) and obviously, command prompt says there is no Java installed. But when I issue command in WSL:

```
java --version
```

I get following results:

```
openjdk 11.0.7 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.7+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.7+10, mixed mode)
```

How do I remove the above and install openjdk 8 in ubuntu (WSL) and Windows.

One of the commands I played with it is: `sudo apt-get remove openjdk*`

sudo apt-get remove openjdk*

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'openjdk-9-jre-headless' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-jdk' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-jre' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-6-jre' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-6-jre-headless' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-11-demo' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-demo' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-11-source' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-jre-dcevm' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-11-jre-headless' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-11-dbg' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-11-doc' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-jdk-headless' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-7-jre-headless' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-jre-zero' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-source' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-jre' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-11-jdk' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-11-jre' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-11-jre-zero' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-7-jdk' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-10-jdk-headless' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-7-jre' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-9-jdk-headless' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-jre-headless' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-11-jre-dcevm' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-11-jdk-headless' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-dbg' for glob 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-doc' for glob 'openjdk*'
Package 'openjdk-6-jre-headless' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-7-jdk' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-6-jre' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-7-jre' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-7-jre-headless' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-9-jre-headless' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-jre' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-9-jdk-headless' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-10-jdk-headless' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-jre-dcevm' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-11-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-11-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-11-jdk' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-11-jdk-headless' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-11-jre' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-11-jre-headless' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-11-source' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-11-demo' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-11-jre-dcevm' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-11-jre-zero' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-demo' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-jdk' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-jdk-headless' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-jre' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-jre-headless' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-jre-zero' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-source' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-dejavu-extra java-common libasound2 libasound2-data libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libgif7
  libice-dev libpcsclite1 libpthread-stubs0-dev libsm-dev libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev
  libxt-dev x11proto-core-dev x11proto-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 140 not upgraded.
```

Comment: You played with it and...?

Comment: @RealSkeptic could you please explain?

Comment: You said you played with that command. What were the results? That is indeed the command to remove a package in Ubuntu.

Comment: @RealSkeptic added the log above.

Answer (score 0):

Wsl is a Linux system on the windows kernel. You should uninstall the JVM with the same Linux tool as you used to install it.

For Ubuntu this is Typically apt or dpkg

If you want to start completely over remove the app and install it again.

Comment: did you mean remove ubuntu?

Comment: @lpt Yes.  SImplest way to revert to a known state when you are not absolutely certain what you are doing.

Comment: Yes, that was only left solution. I reinstalled the Java 8 without WSL. WSL is suprising not a full Linux - has too many restrictions

Comment: @lpt for all practical purposes WSL _is_ Ubuntu (without a graphical display).

Comment: oh okay, thank you. yeah, I use in shell after the fiasco. Meaning I reinstalled ubuntu distro make wsl functional in shell.  May be my above error was related to some of the microsoft's security policies? I do not know, but it seems very strange. I was working on my company provided machine.

Comment: @lpt Company security policy may influence the way you can use the machine. If in doubt, double check what you want to do with them - you may have to do things another way than you think.  Also they may have installed a version if java they want you to use.

Comment: Nope, there was no Java. I installed 11, I  wanted to downgrade to 8.  But this was interesting learning curve.